# If limit of $f(x)$ exists and the limit of $f(x)g(x)$ exists, then does the limit of $g(x)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I was doing some exam preparation and I got stuck on this one. Whats the idea behind this question:

If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a} [f(x)g(x)]$ exist then does $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist?

Thanks..

Comment: Consider the case where $f(x)$ is identically zero.

Comment: The title of your questions mentions a "product of limits" but there is no product of limits in the body of your question, only the limit of a product.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\frac1x$ and let $x\to0$.

Answer (score 3):

There is a theorem, it's called the arithmetic limit theorem I think, and it goes like this:

If $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = K$ then $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)g(x) = KL$.

The statement in your question is sort of a converse to this and the point is probably to make you work out whether it actually holds or not.

Although the OP is not asking for a hint or a solution of the problem:

**Hint**: Try to find a counter example. If you can't come up with one let me know and I'll add one to this answer.

Comment: This is not an answer. It's just the question restated.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar No actually. Read the last sentence.

Comment: The last sentence is the question itself!

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Let me copy and paste the question for you: "Whats the idea behind this question:".

Comment: I'm not only giving the idea, I'm even giving a hint on solving the exam question (which the OP doesn't even ask for)

Comment: Matt is saying that there exists a counter example. This implies the OP's theorem is false.

Answer (score 1):

In general the answer is **NO**.

---

But there is a trivial case in which this is true i.e when $\lim_{n\rightarrow a}{f(x)}$ exists and is non-zero.

A sketch of the proof is as follows.
We know that
if $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}{y(x)}=a$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}{w(x)}=b$ then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}{\left(y(x)\times w(x)\right)}=ab$

Here replace $y(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ and $w(x)=f(x)g(x)$ to arrive at such a proof.

---

Our previous proof helps the task of finding a counter example easier. We can skip all cases $f(x)$ has a limit that is non-zero, rephrasing are limited to the case where $f(x)$ has a limit zero!. One such function is $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ at  $a=0$, see for yourself if $g(x)$ has a limit.

*But this does not mean that if $f(x)$ has a limit $0$ then, $g(x)$ simply cannot have a limit*.

One interesting case of this is when $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}=0$, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)g(x)}$ exists and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}{\frac1{f(x)}}=\infty$. *In this case we can prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}{g(x)}$ exist*. This question has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728904/a-question-about-limits-at-infinity/728957#728957).

Comment: I think you meant limit as x tends to a f(x) goes to infinity  or a non zero number  isnt in the interesting case you were talking of right Sir ?