# Convergence of $u_n$ defined by $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{u_n-1}\frac{1}k\leq n<\sum\limits_{k=1}^{u_n}\frac{1}k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> For every positive integer $n$, define the positive integer $u_n$ by the condition that
>   $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{u_n-1}\frac{1}k\leq n<\sum\limits_{k=1}^{u_n}\frac{1}k$$
>   Let $w_n=\frac1{u_n}$. Does the sequence $(w_n)$ converge and how to prove rigorously it does?

**What I did:**

I proved that $u_n$ exists and is unique, and that $u_1=2$ and $u_2=4$.

Proof of uniqueness:

Suppose that $u_n>v_n$ satisfying the defining condition, then $v_n\leq u_n-1$ so $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{v_n}\frac{1}k\leq n$, which is absurd, thus $u_n$ = $v_n$.

Comment: $u_n\to+\infty$, certainly!

Comment: Did you mean convergence of $u_n$ (small lettered)?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff; @boywholived I made an error, let me correct that

Comment: After Pedro Tamaroff's hint that $u_n\rightarrow +\infty$, observe that $\dfrac{1}{u_n}\cdot u_n =1 \rightarrow 1$, then you can use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728904/a-question-about-limits-at-infinity/728957#728957) to prove that $\dfrac{1}{u_n}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Actually $u_1$ is not unique and to prove that $u_n$ is unique for every $n\geqslant2$ requires to prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^K\frac1k$ is not an integer when $K\geqslant2$ (did you really prove this?).

Comment: @Did cf my edit, is that not enough ?

Comment: Why is "this" (whatever "this" is) absurd?

Comment: @Did Oh i'm really sorry, the second part is a $<$ not a $\leq$

Comment: NOW, every $u_n$ is unique (and $u_1=2$)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$n\lt\sum_{k=1}^{u_n}\frac1k\leqslant1+\int_1^{u_n}\frac{\mathrm dt}t=1+\log u_n\implies\frac1{u_n}\lt\frac{\mathrm e}{\mathrm e^n}$$