# When is a limit of products not a product of limits?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose I have the following limiting expression:

$$\alpha = \lim_{x\to \infty} (f(x) - x^2 g(x))<\infty,$$

with $f,g>0$ for all $x$. Furthermore, suppose $f\to\infty$ and $x^2g\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, but that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} xg(x)=c<\infty$. Can I always replace $xg(x)$ with $c$, e.g. will it always be legal to write

$$\alpha=\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-xc)\quad?$$

Comment: when you approaches to $\infty$, yes you can.

Comment: @mwomath That is not correct! See the answers below for a counter-example.

Comment: Right! I misunderstand because he wrote $xg(x)\to c<\infty$, as $x\to \infty$. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to assume $x^2g(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ here and  not $g(x) \rightarrow \infty$.

Still the statement doesn't have to hold. Let $g(x) =  cx^{-1} + x^{-{3 \over 2}}$ and 
$f(x) = x^2g(x) + \alpha$.

Then automatically $\lim_{x\to \infty} (f(x) - x^2 g(x)) = \alpha$ and also $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} xg(x) = c$

Since $f(x) - xc = x^2g(x) + \alpha - xc = x^2(cx^{-1} + x^{-{3 \over 2}}) + \alpha - xc = x^{1 \over 2} + \alpha$, you have $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) - xc = \infty$ and not $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes you are right. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

If $g(x)\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, then $xg(x)\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728904/a-question-about-limits-at-infinity/728957#728957) for a proof. In other words $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}{xg(x)}$ simply cannot exist.

Comment: Sorry @boywholived, I made a typo in my question. Amended.

Answer (score 1):

While evaluating limits of a complicated expression consisting of many subexpressions connected by $+, -, \times, /$, one should not replace a subexpression by its limit. This is **plain wrong** and the rules of algebra of limits do not allow this. However it seems that it is a common approach followed by students with great success.

The reason this approach works is that there are two specific instances in which this approach is justified.

Let $E$ be a complicated expression whose limit we wish to calculate. And let $B$ be one subexpression of $E$. Let everything else in $E$ apart from $B$ be called $A$. Then we can replace subexpression $B$ by its limit $b$ if either

1) $E = A \pm B$

or

2) $E = A \cdot B$ (in this case $b$ must be non-zero)

Thus the subexpression which we want to replace with its limit must be either connected via $\pm$ or $\times$ with the rest of expression as the other operand of $\pm$ or $\times$. Also the limit of the subexpression must be  non-zero if it is connected by $\times$.

In the current question the expression $E = f(x) - x^{2}g(x)$ and $B = xg(x)$ and limit of $B$ is $c$. We can clearly observe that here we don't have $E = A \pm B$ or $E = A \cdot B$ for some subexpression $A$. Hence we can't replace $B = xg(x)$ by its limit $c$.

This topic has been explained with examples in my [blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-2.html) under the heading "Misuse of Rules of Limits".

Comment: Thank you for the insight - very clear and helpful.

Comment: @pbs: By the way in case you noticed we can also replace $\times $ with $/$ in the above answer because we can write $A/B = A\times (1/B)$ and $(1/B) \to 1/b \neq 0$.

Comment: yes I noticed this on your blog also.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not legal. For example, take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}$. Then $x^2g(x)=x-1$, so
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x)-x^2g(x))=\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-x+1)=1.
$$
And $xg(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$, so $c=1$. But
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-xc)=0.
$$
When you replace $x^2g(x)$ with $xc$ inside the limits, the error is in
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2 g(x)= x\lim_{x\to\infty} xg(x)= xc.
$$